# How do I use the .count function on a string to check for 2 of the same characters?

Tags: string, python-3.x, count, charactercount

I need to use the .count thing and combine it with an if statement to check for 2 of the same characters in a string

I've got nothing so far

Also I'm a beginner in python so please use easy stuff for me to understand

Comment: Show what you have done,please.

Comment: Wild guess: OP is either using a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or should be using one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
>>> if 'aba'.count('a') >= 2: print (True)
else: print(False)

True
```